# Is there a minimum timeout to InetAddress isReachable method?

Tags: java, inetaddress

I'm having a weird behavior with the `isReachable` method of `InetAddress` class.

[Method prototype](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)) is :

```
public boolean isReachable(int timeout)
```

- When using a **timeout > 1500 (ms)**, the method waits the exact time
  given as argument (if the target IP is not reachable of course...).
- When using **timeout < 1500**, the method waits 1000ms maximum...

The code is quite simple :

```
    InetAddress addr = null;
    String ip = "10.48.2.169";

    try {
        addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Timestamp s = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println(s + "\t Starting tests :");

    pingTest(addr, 100);
    pingTest(addr, 500);
    pingTest(addr, 1000);
    pingTest(addr, 1500);
    pingTest(addr, 2000);
    pingTest(addr, 2500);
```

Where pingTest is defined by :

```
public static void pingTest(InetAddress addr, int timeout) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            result = addr.isReachable(timeout);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Timestamp s = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(s + "\t (" + timeout + ") " + addr.toString() + " " + result);
    }
```

Then the output is :

```
2017-09-07 16:45:41.573  Starting tests :
2017-09-07 16:45:42.542  (100) /10.48.2.169 false
2017-09-07 16:45:43.542  (500) /10.48.2.169 false
2017-09-07 16:45:44.541  (1000) /10.48.2.169 false
2017-09-07 16:45:46.041  (1500) /10.48.2.169 false
2017-09-07 16:45:48.041  (2000) /10.48.2.169 false
2017-09-07 16:45:50.541  (2500) /10.48.2.169 false
```

So the question is : **Is there a minimum timeout to InetAddress isReachable method ?** (like 1500 in my doubt, but I doubt, huge timeout...)

Or maybe I just made a huge mistake that I still miss...

Tell me if this isn't clear enough.

Thanks for your help and thoughts.

Comment: Take a look at this OpenJDK [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143397) where a user reports an undocumented minimum timeout (search for the term "minimum"). While this report is hardly definitive, it may help corroborate your experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should notice that the behavior of INetAddress.isReachable is not the same on each platform supported by Java. I will assume you work on Windows.

When undocumented behavior happens you should always look at the source if they are available. The java.net implementation for windows is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/java/net) for the OpenJDK (it should be quite similar for the Oracle JVM, but I am not sure of this).

What we saw in the `isReachable` method implementation is:

1. they don't rely on ping because they find the Windows ICMP protocol implementation too unreliable
2. they pass the timeout value to the `NET_Wait` function

So **the isReachable method doesn't perform a ping** and we need to check what the `NET_Wait` do with the timeout to understand why a less than 1 second timeout isn't possible.

The `NET_Wait` function is defined here: [src/windows/native/java/net/net_util_md.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/java/net/net_util_md.c)

It consist in an infinite loop which break when these events occurs during the `select` function call:

- `NET_WAIT_CONNECT` on the socket file descriptor (socket is connected to the remote host)
- The timeout ends

The `select` function is documented in a man page you may consult [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). This man page tells us that the timeout can "be rounded up to the system clock granularity, and kernel scheduling delays mean that the blocking interval may overrun by a small amount".

This is why there is no guarantee on the minimal timeout value. Also, I think that the documentation doesn't state any minimal timeout value because the implementation differs on OSs supported by the JVM.

Hope this helps you understanding why.

However, to achieve a wanted timeout you may test the reachability in a separate task. You wait until the task returns the result, or if you wait more than your timeout you cancel the task or ignore its results.